# Custom query for certain post type OR another post type with a certain category

Tags: wp-query, loop, taxonomy, tax-query, post-type

I want to display posts that are either

- EITHER Post Type A
- OR Post Type B but ONLY if they are also in CATEGORY 1

Is that at all posible? How do I built my custom query?

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

You can filter by querying by post type, or in a single query (code between /* */).

```
<?php
//This is the first query
$query_A = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_type_A', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //'cache_results' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'ids'//add by Achim Baur
);
$query_A['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'the_taxonomy_here',
        'terms' => $_REQUEST['term_here'],
    )
);
//End the first query

//This is the second query
$query_B = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_type_B', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cache_results' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'ids'//add by Achim Baur
);
$query_B['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'the_taxonomy_here',
        'terms' => $_REQUEST['term_here'],
    )
);
//End the second query

//merge IDs
$post_ids = array_merge($query_A,$query_B);


//This is the final query
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'any', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //'cache_results' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
);

//or simply, any post type in one query
/*$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'any', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cache_results' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'the_taxonomy_here',
            'terms' => $_REQUEST['term_here'],
        ),
    ),
);*/

$posts = new WP_Query($query);
while($posts->have_posts()){
    //Write something here
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer is just code, can you add some explanation of what it does and how it answers the question so it can be understood?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll do it, Tom!
But what did you think about the code?

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that put me in the right direction. I had to add 'fields' => 'ids' to both query A and B to make it work.

Comment: Excellent! 
I'll edit the code